# Set Link Target Checkbox chcked on Edit Image MOdal Window in Admin Post Edit Screen?

Tags: admin, wp-editor, images

Inside of newer versions of WordPress in the Visual Editor when you add a photo, you can then click on it which reveals an `Edit`, `Delete`, and `Resize` buttons.

[image]

Now if you click on the Edit button shown in the image above.  It will insert a Modal window into the DOM which has more settings for the image, like the image below...

[image]

In the image you can see a section `Advanced Options` which has a setting Checkbox `open link in new window/tab`

My client want me to modify his WordPress to make that Checkbox be checked by default so that he doesn't have to do it himself for every image.

I initially thought I could just make it checked using JavaScript/jQuery with something like this...

```
jQuery(document).ready( function () {

    jQuery(".link-target input[type='checkbox']").prop({
      checked: true
    });

});
```

However this does not work and probably because it seems the Modal is added to the DOM after you click on the button to edit the image.

I am hoping someone can help me come up with a solution to this maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well... WordPress uses the `wpeditimage` tinymce plugin to perform the tasks for the "Add Media" editor button.

When you click the pencil icon to edit the image... the `wpeditimage` plugin will read the image code, and determine if there is a value of `_blank` for the `target` attribute.

If the value is `_blank`; the plugin will check the box when the modal window is opened.  If not, the box is left unchecked.

You can see this code in action in `wp-includes/js/tinymce/plugins/wpeditimage/plugin.js`, at line number 217:

```
metadata.linkTargetBlank = dom.getAttrib( link, 'target' ) === '_blank' ? true : false;
```

So... to be checked by default... each time an image is inserted into the editor.. it would need to also have the following attribute and value; `target="_blank"`.

Now... the only way to get the box to be checked... is to already have the value of `target="_blank"` on the `<a>` link wrapping the image when inserting into the editor.  For this; we will use the [image_send_to_editor](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/image_send_to_editor/) filter.

```
add_filter('image_send_to_editor', 'my_add_target_blank', 10, 8);
function my_add_target_blank($html, $id, $caption, $title, $align, $url, $size, $alt = '' ){

    // check if there is already a target value
    if ( preg_match('/<a.*? target=".*?">/', $html) ) {
        $html = preg_replace('/(<a.*? target=".*?)(".*?>)/', '$1 ' . '_blank' . '$2', $html);
    } else {
        $html = preg_replace('/(<a.*?)>/', '$1 target="' . '_blank' . '" >', $html);
    }
    return $html;
}
```

That should take care of adding the `target="_blank"` attribute to the `<a>` tag wrapping the inserted image.

Now, if you click to edit the image (right after insertion)... you'll notice the "Open link in new tab/window" option is now checked.

Happy Coding!

Comment: Amazing, I wasn't really expecting anyone to actually be able to answer this one, thanks!!

Comment: I saw that in your profle the link to http://www.ultimatetinymcepro.com/ which seems to be down but from the name of it, I take it this area is your specialty, looks like I got lucky that you saw my post so thank you!  I'm actually pretty interested to see what other sorts of mods you have done to the editor area as I might be able to sell my client into mods that make there life easier, I have one client who is a book author and spends up to 10 hours a day in the Editor window so he pays for things that make it better and easier for him

Comment: Wow - 10 hours a day from the front end??  I spend about 10 hours a day in the back end ;)  Perhaps the two of us would be quite the whole... lol.  I'll fix my profile link.. thanks for that.  I decided to "kill" an old plugin; and start anew.  Please feel free to use any of my contact forms.. include a link here so I know who you are.. and we can continue there.  Thanks again, my friend!